# maintain state of YouTubePlayerSupportFragment inside a fragment, while recreating the layout of the fragment

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, master-detail, android-youtube-api

i'm trying to show a YouTubePlayerSupportFragment inside a fragment in a master-detail flow,
i'm defining the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment programatically by replacing a FrameLayout with this fragment, inside a fragment 
the thing is, when i change the device orientation, i want the fragment layout to change, but still maintaining the player's position on orientation change (when the video is playing, it keeps playing, not restart from initial state).
i defined two layout for landscape and portraits (/layout-sw600dp-land & /layout-sw600dp-port)
to get this behaviour, i'm using these lines in the manifest to prevent activity recreation (to maintain the player state)

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

and on the fragment OnConfigurationChanged method, i told the fragment to remove all view and recreate the view

the question is, how do i maintain the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment state (isPlaying, videos on the list, position etc) while re-creating the layout for the fragment?
because the FrameLayout containing the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment is also removed, and i intend to reattach this fragment to the new layout and make it reload it's current state
so roughly, the layout i want looks like this (sorry haven't had enough reputation to show it here)
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFBZc.jpg)

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Hugo i didnt continue the project lol sorry, but the possible solution i think is to not remove all the view, just re-arrange it programatically, by using relativelayout's .addRule function, in the image i provided just set the viewgroups' rule to set below the other one

Comment: We tried by adding and removing some layoutparam but the youtubeplayerFragment seem to stop the video when you are doing this. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: it seems like some view overlaid the YouTubePlayer, YouTubePlayer should always be the topmost on the screen or else it will be stopped, YouTube's API policy, we can't do anything about it.. sorry for late reply, i didn't check sof so often

Comment: i'm looking for solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526975/youtubeplayerfragment-black-screen-on-orientation-changes .I'm trying to create fragment and detach/attach it.no success ( have you found solution?
@Hugo