# YouTubePlayerFragment black screen on orientation changes

Tags: android, video, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to keep playing `YouTubePlayerFragment` on orientation changes.

the code looks like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    populateViewForOrientation(inflater, frameLayout);
    return frameLayout;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    populateViewForOrientation(inflater, (ViewGroup) getView());
}

private void populateViewForOrientation(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    viewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    rootView = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResId(), viewGroup);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    if (frYTube != null) {
       FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       transaction.replace(R.id.frame, frYTube);
       transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

fragment replaced (i see text on it) and the music is playing but instead of video - black screen.
How can i deal with it? is it possible to get video back? btw, if after rotation next video is oppenes - the video appears.
i've tried to call `pause` and `play` for current video - it dosen't help.
i haven't try `YouTubePlayerView` because i use `moxy` so i need to deal with fragment.

**upd**

it looks like to create custom view with `YouTubePlayerFragment` inside have more stable behavior (and remove add view then). but the black screen problem still exists.

it's possible to restore video in this case with:

```
 mYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(url);
 ...
 public void onLoaded(String s) {
  mYouTubePlayer.seekToMillis(mills);
```

but there is no sense too reload video, i'm trying to avoid this - the delay appears

Comment: have you got the solution, even I am facing same issue.

Comment: Hello @pooja. my current solution is to not inflate new layout. I handle orientation changing manually, removes and adds components that changes position progrommatically and not touch youtube frame :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way i found and it works is to handle screen orientation manually:

1) add to your activity:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

2) in activity class:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   someFunctionToHandleOrienttion();
}
```

and you shouldn't inflate new layout. just remove and recreate/add all you need except `youtubeframe` to make land layout looks you want. it's a bit tricky and strange, but in other cases you got black screen instead video.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012754/android-youtube-api-v3-orientation#comment21122394_15012754), make sure that you are initializing the `YouTubePlayerView` in `onCreate()` when `onCreate()` was called during a restore rather than an explicit create. Here's a [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Streaming-Youtube-Videos-with-YouTubePlayerView) in which the activity containing the fragment does not need to extend any special base class.

You may also check this related thread: [Screen orientation not working with youtubePlayerfragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670774/screen-orientation-not-working-with-youtubeplayerfragment)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll check tutorials. hmm, I haven't create it in `onCreate` because I need to create video frame on a fragment by user action. I need to check if it might be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and easy solution is to add the following to your video activity, in your manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

I have an app that uses this for a video and it works just fine. Everything lays out properly on orientation change, and the activity and fragment instance do not get torn down allowing it to seamlessly continue to play.

If you want the activity to be torn down/recreated, while retaining the fragment instance, please re-read the documentation for **setRetainInstance()**.

There are some subtle nuances that you need to be aware of to get this to work properly: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

**Using this it will continue playing the fragment after the orientation change**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried `setRetainInstance` (`configChanges` already setted up). but the result the same: i can listen to the sound but video is black until i call `loadVideo` for next item.